# I'm trying to run emulator on flutter anyone know solving?

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart, android-emulator

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'C:\src\Flutter projeleri\dar_t1\flutter_application_1\android\app\build.gradle' line: 27
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

> Could not get unknown property 'stacktrace' for project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Comment: Do you have "Android Studio" Software? If not download it and update me so I give you guidelines.

Comment: I did, I download emulator as well but when I click start without debbuging it says that error

Comment: try install fresh flutter and see if the error persist